# os.system behaves differently w/ input from raw_input() vs file.readlines()

Tags: python

I am running a command through os.system and can get the command needed in two different ways; from user input or from a file.

```
# Code works fine with this
filename = raw_input('Enter a filename:' )

# but it doesn't work if I do this:
f = open("userinput.txt").readlines()
filename = f[1]
```

If I now print filename I get exactly the same output. However when filename is passed through os.system it only works in the top case. The other case prints some data I did not ask for. I would post full source code but the files are huge! Here is the a snippit.

```
string = "sort -n -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 < "
string1 = "> orderedfile.txt"

cmd = string + filename + string1
reordering = os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Building commands with string concatenation is innately buggy and you shouldn't be doing it to start with. It's like using the same mechanism to generate SQL queries -- someone gives you a filename that contains `$(rm -rf ~)` and you just hosed your account.

Comment: That said, this code is really messy. It's referring to a `sideview` variable it never sets, and it's defining `string2` even though it never uses that either.

Comment: They are defined just not in the snippet posted

Comment: That's my point. Code posted here should be a [mcve], that someone else can copy-and-paste to see the same problem. That kind of bugs prevents others from reproducing behavior, and thus from being able to check their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Current Behavior

`readlines()` returns lines with `\n` on the end of them. Thus, you're splitting the code you run into two separate commands. Assuming your file is `unsorted_input.txt`, then, this would run:

```
sort -n -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 < unsorted_input.txt
> orderedfile.txt
```

...thus, it writes the output of `sort` to stdout, and truncates `orderedfile.txt` to be empty.

The smallest possible fix is just to trim the trailing newline from the filename -- but that leaves you open to lots of other bugs: Filenames with spaces, filenames with literal quotes, filenames with command substitutions or combinations thereof will throw the original approach into chaos.

---

#### Preferred Approach (No Shell Required)

A correct implementation would look more like:

```
import subprocess

def sort_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    subprocess.call(['sort', '-n', '-k3,3', '-k2,2', '-k1,1'],
                    stdin=open(input_filename, 'r'),
                    stdout=open(output_filename, 'w'))

sort_file(
    open('userinput.txt', 'r').readlines()[1].rstrip('\n'),
    'output_file.txt',
)
```

#### Preferred Approach (Safe Shell Usage)

```
def sort_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    subprocess.call(
        ['sort -n -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 <"$1" >"$2"', # this is the shell script to run
         '_',                                     # this becomes $0 when that script runs
         input_filename,                          # this becomes $1
         output_filename],                        # this becomes $2
        shell=True)
```

Note in this case that we're passing filenames **out of band** from code, and quoting the expansions where they're used.

Comment: Many Thanks, that will be it!

Comment: Please see the edit demonstrating a best-practice approach. You're risking security bugs when you append strings together to form commands.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - very useful. Will keep this in mind!